# GLM: How to test if an alternative predictor variable is better

Tags: generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, negative-binomial-distribution, likelihood-ratio

I have a simple model where the expectation of the outcome variable `y` is proportional to a predictor variable `x1`. The outcome variable is assumed to have a negative binomial distribution. I estimate the relationship using a GLM with identity link and the intercept forced through the origin. The dispersion parameter of the negative binomial distribution is estimated my maximizing the likelihood. I have a dataset with ~ 600 entries to calibrate my model.

Now there has come up an alternative predictor I can use, `x2`. In my current understanding, I should prefer the predictor that gives me the highest likelihood, given that I want to represent the underlying distribution as well as possible. Indeed, `x2` gives a larger likelihood value than `x1`, but only slightly so.

My question is: *Can I use some kind of test to prove that `x2` is a better predictor than `x1`, in terms of likelihood ratio etc.?*

Comment: No, you could use nested models (y~x1 and y~x1+x2) to test whether adding the new variable significantly improves the model. Otherwise predictions from a test set may be used to assess the better variable at predicting.

Comment: What metric should I use to assess model improvement?

Comment: If talking about nested models you can run an ANOVA on the two models, which will perform a Chi-square test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Wilks' theorem, if the two models are the same, then $-2 \log \Lambda $ is $\chi^2$-distributed (where $\Lambda$ is the likelihood ratio). The statistic and its p-value can be obtained, e.g., by running `anova(x1, x2)` in R, where `x1` and `x2` are results from the `glm` function.

I discovered this result after being pointed in the right direction by [user2974951](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/143489/user2974951)'s comment above.